# Calculating the euclidean distance for each value in the matrix given a fixed window size

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have `MxN` matrix. For each value `i` in the matrix and window of size `s`, I need to calculate, the sum of `(Euclidean distance between the value i and it's neighbor * output from weight function)`.

Currently, I am calculating as follows:

```
def some_weight_function(sigma, x):
   return np.exp(-np.square(x/sigma))

original = np.random.random((200,200))
final = np.zeros(origina.shape)

neighbors = 4

for row in range(M):
   for col in range(N):
      top_left, bottom_right = square_window_coordinates(total_neightbors = neighbors)
      # This gets top left coordinates for 9x9 window and 
      # bottom right coordinates for the same 9x9 window

      w = 0

      for ii in range(top_left[0], bottom_right[0]):
           for jj in range(top_left[1], bottom_right[1]):
                 euclidean = np.sqrt(np.square(ii-col) + np.square(jj-row))
                 weight = euclidean * some_weight_function(10, ii)
                 w += weight

           final[r][c] = w

print("Final matrix has been prepared")
print(final)
```

Everything works fine above. But the problem is, it becomes very very slow if the matrix size increases or the window size increases. What are the ways I could vectorize the three nested loops? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: This is too much. What is `some_weight_function()`? It's not gonna be possible to vectorize if you need to make a function call

Comment: inb4 "use `np.vectorize`" because that's a wrapper over a `for` loop. We'll need to know that calculation

Comment: @roganjosh Have added the definition of `some_weight_function`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going to find a way to vectorize that very easily with your windowing.  However, you could certainly speed up some of the math!  I'd try that first and see if the time is acceptable.

Let's look at your euclidean distance function.  If your window size is 9x9, then there are only 81 possible inputs, with fixed outputs.  You could could either put in a helper function (outside the loop) with a lookup table or cache the results.  The point being that if your matrix is 200 x 200 and your window is 9 x 9, you are doing 3 million+ square root operations unnecessarily.  Square rooting is a very slow math operation.

You could also do this for your weighting function, which appears to have a small, fixed number of inputs based on the window position (?!)  Is that right?

Anyhow, here is an example of using caching and timing differences:

```
# cache example

import numpy as np
from functools import lru_cache

def euclidean(delta_x, delta_y):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(delta_x) + np.square(delta_y))


@lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)   # big enough for 9x9 window
def cached_euclidean(delta_x, delta_y):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(delta_x) + np.square(delta_y))



def exercise(reps):
    for d_x in range(-4, 5):
        for d_y in range(-4, 5):
            euc_dist = euclidean(d_x, d_y)

def exercise_cached(reps):
    for d_x in range(-4, 5):
        for d_y in range(-4, 5):
            euc_dist = cached_euclidean(d_x, d_y)
```

Exercising this with timeit:

```
In [6]: %run cache_it                                                           

In [7]: %timeit exercise(3000000)                                               
266 µs ± 3.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit exercise_cached(3000000)                                        
11.6 µs ± 106 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [9]:
```

Note the cached example is 20x faster for ~3M hits.

Also, it looks like your neighbors function does not depend on your location in the matrix, so you should move that outside of your nested loop as well.  Right now, you appear to be calling it MxN times unnecessarily, when you could just call it once before the loop because the window values do not depend on M, N.

Comment: Could we also use `lru_cache` with an argument type as `numpy.ndarray`? Currently it gives an error saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`